# How to convert an unknown Bigint date-time format to date-time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a fairly dirty database that I am working w/ at the moment.
The DB has dates that look like this, `1546330742` *and* this `2019-01-01 03:18:13`.

Previously, I have tried using almost all of the different increments of time provided by Pandas' `to_datetime` function. I've had the best luck with using seconds, as they're often off by a few hours, which I converted to UTC so that it would line up with the data we presently have (roughly ~3 hours).

Doing the following yields the above described behavior:

`pd.to_datetime(df["arrival_time"], unit='s')`

However, some of the data entries result in some absolutely ridiculous conversions; where they go from `2019-01-01 21:23:55` to `1969-12-31 19:00:00`. This is not all of the entries, but some of them. This is all one database/source of data.

So to summarize:

- Inital conversion results in ~3-7 hours off of the local time (which I assumed to be the difference in time-zones
- Some conversion results in the data being read as 1969 (which seems very wrong)
- Data is formatted in `1546330742` and `2019-01-01 03:18:13`

I don't know what the original date was, or what the bigint converts to.

**How do I identify the conversion of this source date/ convert it properly when the "conversion rate" is unknown?**

Is there a standard that I am missing? (I was under the impression these are typically stored in ms but that did not prove to be the case).

Comment: The `POSIX` origin is `1970-01-01` so since you're getting a date before that, you have a negative integer in that place (in this particular case `-18000`). Since these are timespans, and seemingly recent timespans, perhaps a negative placeholder was used when the data was not available when it was generated, that is the end of the time-span has yet to happen.

Comment: You could likely verify this a bit more by checking if *all* dates before 1970-01-01 are exactly the same. If that's the case, then probably a place holder value, though -18000 seems like a somewhat perculiar choice.